# Ember bind action from property

Tags: ember.js

In Ember I am trying to bind an action in a template from a property in the view.

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
items: [
    {title: Em.I18n.t("admin.action.clone"), icon: "copy", action: "clone"},
    {title: Em.I18n.t("admin.action.new"), icon: "plus", action: "new"}
]
});
```

and in the template:

```
{{#each itm in view.items}}
        <a {{action itm.action}}>{{itm.title}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Action takes the literal string `itm.action` and doesnt execute the binding. resulting in an error saying itm.action wasnt handled.

Is there a way I can make the action helper execute that binding before it goes bubbling for an action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to trigger the item-specific action in a proxy handler method:

#### View

```
App.MyView = Ember.View.extend({
  items: [
    {title: Em.I18n.t("admin.action.clone"), icon: "copy", action: "clone"},
    {title: Em.I18n.t("admin.action.new"), icon: "plus", action: "new"}
  ],

  actions: {
    handleItemClick: function(item) {
      var action = item.get('action');
      this.send(action);
    }
  }
});
```

#### Template

```
{{#each itm in view.items}}
  <a {{action "handleItemClick" itm target="view"}}>{{itm.title}}</a>
{{/each}}
```

---

**EDIT**:

Dynamic action names are now in master. Have a look at: https://github.com/rjackson/ember.js/commit/7396b37172b59e27647a07574ea7051ab06d001a

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was just trying just this! and it works as expected. I was really looking for a more generic way so that my template doesnt have to be bound to a specific handler. an idea was to create that handler on the application route/controller but I would have to find a way to bubble it down to my active route/controller which is not possible/catholic IMHO.

Comment: this is great news! unfortunatly I cannot use canary builds in my app. has to be a proper release! thanks for the info!